# NODEJS : Front end and back end on different port?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm coding a NodeJS website with frond end / backend. It is advised to seperate files so my front end will ask for data via API to my back end.

Is it good practice to have Front End and Back End on the same server ? Do I need to run them on different port ?

Comment: Internally maybe because only one program can listen on a port but you can add a reverse proxy like nginx so that externally you are only using port 80/443

Comment: Depends. You frontend (i gues) is a web app and talks to your backend via http/ws/what ever. Thus you dont need a port for your frontend app per sé. Put nginx as webserver in front of both, and serve your frontend via nginx and forward request to your api via nginx configured as reverse proxy. node should not be run directly "as infanerty frontline" app.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bad practice to have a frontend and backend on the same server, but it's not ideal too if your frontend is static.

If you're familiar with a cloud provider you could put your static front end files on cloud storage (AWS S3, Google cloud storage, or Azure Storage,...)

To serve frontend and backend from the same server, you could do the following:

in your node.js server, you could use the same express app to serve the backend and the frontend.

At this level, you don't have to use different ports, because you'll have to create two express instances listening on two different ports.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

/* serve your API */
app.use("/api", router);

/* serve your front (stored in the public folder) */
app.use("/", express.static("public"));

/* API routes */
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ data: "response to get" });
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ data: "response to post" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port} ...`);
});
```

Finally, to serve your frontend and backend to your end-users, you could use Nginx as a reverse proxy server, configure two different ports, and you could also support HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

yes you cant listen to port which already in use
run nodejs server on random port and serve front-end with webserver (nginx,apache ...)